# Docker-Desktop for MAC Kubernetes not creating secrets or token for serviceaccounts

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I'm just trying to create a simple service account. Theoretically, kubectl automatically creates the secret and token for service accounts... But, not in my case... I've done this in `kube-system`, `default`, and new/other namespaces.

```
me@mymachine ~ % kubectl create serviceaccount my-acct
serviceaccount/my-acct created
me@mymachine ~ % kubectl describe serviceaccount my-acct
Name:                my-acct
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
```

I have reset the Kubernetes system. Uninstalled, removed ./kube/ and removed the Library...
Still no secret created. All of my developers machines (MAC as well, both Intel and M1) automatically create the account secret.
Any ideas?

Comment: I have come upon the basic root of this issue... The update to Kubernetes v1.22.5 to v1.24.0 that occurs within the software update for Docker-Desktop from version 4.7.1 to 4.8.x changes the kubernetes configuration... If you install a fresh 4.8.x Docker-Desktop, creating a service account will NOT automatically create the associated secret or token from the API.
If you are in Version 4.7.1 or have updated to 4.8.x and have NOT 'Reset Kubernetes cluster' in the preference or troubleshoot page, the serviceaccount works as advertised.

Comment: In my case I had recently updated to docker-desktop 4.11.1.   We bring up our development environment using [tilt](https://tilt.dev/).   I noticed that many of the deployments were not coming healthy because secrets were missing, hence came to this issue.   But the root cause turned out to be a typo in an environment ConfigMap (illegal key name) which resulted in subsequent items (including the secrets) not being deployed, with little explanation (until I went digging for it). So, be sure to check _all_ of your config.

Answer (score 2):

Docker-Desktop 4.7.1 includes the appropriate Kubernetes configuration for the controller manager and api service to automatically create secrets and tokens when creating a service account.

Docker-Desktop 4.8.x does not have this configuration. Fresh install or resetting the Kubernetes cluster will prevent the secret and token from automatically being created upon service account creation

Comment: Can  you explain how to fix the issue in these versions?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: This answer will not "fix" the automatic creation of secrets for service accounts, but shows how you can associate a secret to a service account.

For the newer Docker Desktop 4.8.1 (for Mac), you can create the secret manually:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: default-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: default
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF
```

And then you can associate the secret to the service account by editing the service account configuration, run:

```
kubectl edit serviceaccounts default
```

There you can add the secret, at the end, like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "XXXX-XX-XXTXX:XX:XXZ"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "XXXX"
  uid: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
secrets:
- name: default-secret
```

After that, you'll be able to use the token for the required purposes.